# Partial ordered set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider the set $\{9,3,56,4,2,15,1544,8,112,675,20,336,772,28,405,45,224,135\}$ with the binary relation if x divides y. Show that the relation is a partial order.

These are the only directions my teacher provided. I am a little confused.. are the x and y values the set of numbers and I just determine which are divisible by each other?

Answer (score 2):

To show partial ordering, you have to show three things. First, let $S$ be your set. 
1) Reflexivity: $a|a$ for all $a \in S$ 
2) Anti-symmetry: $a|b$ and $b|a$ implies that $a = b$ 
3) Transitivity: $a|b$ and $b|c$ implies that $a|c$.

Reflexivity is trivial. Anti-symmetry takes a bit more work. So suppose $a|b$ and $b|a$. Then $aq = b$ and $bx = a$ for some $q, x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $aqx = a \implies qx = 1$. Since $q, x \in \mathbb{Z}$, $q = x = \pm1$. Since you are dealing with strictly positive integers, you can assume $q = x = 1$ and thus, $a = b$.

Transitivity is pretty straight-forward. Suppose $x|y$ and $y|z$ for some $x, y, z \in S$. Then $xq = y$ and $yk = z$ for $q, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. It follows that $xqk = z$. And so let $c = qk$. So $xc = z$, satisfying the definition of divisibility for $x|z$. We conclude transitivity.

Comment: alright makes sense. My x and y values are only the ones in the set given right?

Comment: the set doesn't matter ... $a|b$ is a partial order on any set of integers ... though you could illustrate transitivity for the above set by looking at things like $3|9$ and $9|45$ and $3|45$ and also $45|135$ and $3|135$

Comment: yeah I was going to illustrate it by going case by case through the set

Comment: It's a partial order on $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$. I would be careful about working with $\mathbb{Z}$ as a whole, due to issues with negative numbers. You'll run into an issue with anti-symmetry, which I pointed out in my answer. :-)

Comment: even if you set was $\{5,8\}$ then again $|$ is a partial order on it ... not a very interesting one since all you could say is $5|5$ and $8|8$, which is not much, but it is a partial order anyway, in which $5$ and $8$ are not related, or not comparable.

Comment: Right, but if you have $\{-5, 5\}$, anti-symmetry becomes sticky. Since $5(-1) = -5$ and $-5(-1) = 5$. Both clearly divide each other but are not equal. If we say their magnitudes are equal, then we could say this would be a partial order.

Comment: the question does not insist that you are dealing with positive integers only ... even if you say so in your answer. But $5|-25$ since $5(-5)=-25$, so I see no problem working with all integers positive or negative, or even $0$, note that $a|0$ for all $a$.

Comment: @ml0105 you are right, if negative integers are allowed that will not be a partial order ... it would be more generally a so called partial pre-order, but that is another mater.

Comment: There are only positive numbers in the set so how could we be dealing with negative numbers?

Comment: That's the point. When we're dealing with $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$, we can prove divisibility is a partial order, no problem. Check out my response on anti-symmetry to see where I discuss this some.